# Can anyone explain ARM based Linux machine reboot procedure in detail

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

How reboot procedure works on ARM SOCs running Linux, e.g do boot loaders reinitialize DDR memory? can anybody please explain me rebooting process in detail.

Comment: These details are highly vendor- and chip-dependent.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to create a 'log' area to trace events that lead to a crash, you can tell Linux that it has less memory than it does.  For most cases, DDR will hold up over a boot cycle and you can re-read the memory.  You may wish to add some checksum to validate the regions.  The main issue is that neither the boot loader nor the OS goes and zeros the memory.  Or maybe you are trying to do something else?  NOTE:  100% formally this will not work.  Typical DDR will hold charge for several seconds, but the worst case might be uS/mS range depending on caps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is way too broad. It's not only SoC vendor dependent, but also hardware and software dependent.

**However, the most typical setup is:**

1. CPU executes first-stage bootloader (FSB).

   FSB is located on the chip itself in ROM or EEPROM and is very small (AT91RM9200 FSB is 10kB max, AFAIR). FSB then initializes minimum set of peripherals (clocks, RAM, flash), transfers second-stage bootloader (U-Boot) to RAM, and executes it.
2. U-Boot starts.

   U-Boot initializes some other hardware (serial, ethernet, etc), transfers Linux kernel to RAM, prepares the pointer to kernel input parameters and jumps into it's entry point.
3. Linux kernel starts.

   Magic happens here. The system now able to serve you cookies via SSH console and/or executes whatever needs to be executed.

**A bit more in-depth info about *warm start***:

*Warm start* is a software reset, while *cold start* is power-on or hardware reset. Some (most?) SoC's are able to pass the info to FSB/SSB about warm start. This way bootloaders are able to minimize the overall boot time by skipping re-initializion of already initialized peripherals.

Again, this is most typical setup from my 15+ years experience in embedded world.

Answer (score 1):

> How reboot procedure works on ARM SOCs running Linux, ... ?

The typical ARM processor in use today is integrated with peripherals on a single IC called a **SoC**, system on a chip.  Typically the reboot procedure is nearly identical to a power-on boot procedure.  On a reset the ARM processor typically jumps to address 0.

Main memory, e.g. DRAM, and non-volatile storage, e.g. NAND flash, are typically external to the SoC (that is Linux capable) for maximum design flexibility.
But typically there is a small (perhaps 128KB) embedded ROM (read-only memory) to initialize the minimal system components (e.g. clocks, external memories) to begin bootstrap operations. A processor reset will cause execution of this boot ROM. (This ROM is truly read-only, and cannot be modified. The code is masked into the silicon during chip fabrication.)
The SoC may have a strapping option to instead execute an external boot memory, such as NOR flash or EEPROM, which can be directly executed (i.e. XIP, execute in place).
The salient characteristic of any ROM, flash, and SRAM that the first-stage boot program uses is that these memories must be accessible immediately after a reset.

One of the problems of bootstrapping a system that uses DRAM for main memory is its hardware initialization. The DRAM memory controller has to be initialized with board-specific parameters before code can be loaded into DRAM and executed. So from where does this board-specific initialization code execute, since it can't be in main memory?
Each vendor has their own solution.
Some require memory configuration data to be stored in nonvolatile memory for the boot ROM to access.
Some SoCs have integrated SRAM (which does not require initialization like DRAM) to execute a small second-stage bootstrap program.
Some SoCs use NOR flash to hold a XIP (execute in place) bootstrap program (e.g. the SPL program of U-Boot).

Each SoC vendor has its own bootstrap method to get the OS loaded and executing.
Some use hardware strapping read through GPIO pins to determine the source of the next stage of the bootstrap sequence.
Another vendor may use an ordered list of memories and devices to probe for a bootstrap program.
Another technique, is to branch to firmware in NOR flash, which can be directly executed (i.e. XIP, execute in place).

Once the bootstrap program has initialized the DRAM, then this main memory can be used to load the next stage of booting. That could be a sophisticated boot utility such as U-Boot, or (if the bootstrap program is capable) the Linux kernel. A ROM boot program could do everything to load an ARM Linux kernel (e.g. ETRAX), but more common is that there will be several bootstrap programs or stages that have be performed between processor reset to execution of the OS.

The requirements of booting the Linux ARM kernel are spelled out in the following document: [Booting ARM Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting)
Older versions of Linux ARM used the ATAGs list to pass basic configuration information to the kernel. Modern versions provide a complete board configuration using a compiled binary of a Device Tree.

> ... e.g do boot loaders reinitialize DDR memory?

Of the few examples that I have seen, the boot programs unconditionally configure the dynamic RAM controller.

PCs have a BIOS and Power On Self Tests, aka POST.  The execution of POST is the primary difference between a power-on reset (aka cold boot) versus a software reset (aka warm boot or reboot).  ARM systems typically do not perform POST, so you typically will see minimal to no difference between types of reset.

Answer (score 0):

It varies a lot depending on the SoC. I'll describe something like a "typical" one (Freescale iMX6)...

Typically an on-chip Watchdog Timer is used to reset the SoC cleanly. Sometimes, an external Power Management IC can be provoked to perform a board-wide reset (this method may be better, as it avoids the risk of external chips getting "stuck" in an unexpected state, but not all board designs support it).

Upon reset, the SoC will start its normal boot process: checking option pins, fuse settings and initializing clocks and the boot device (e.g. eMMC). This is typically controlled by CPU code executing from a small on-chip ROM.

*Either* the internal boot ROM will initialize DDR SDRAM (using settings taken from fuses or read from a file on the boot device), *or* the bootloader gets loaded into internal RAM then it takes care of DDR initialization (and other things). The U-Boot bootloader can be configured to work either way.

Finally, the kernel and DTB are loaded into memory and started.

Comment: The code in the on-chip ROM is from the CPU vendor (ARM in this case) or from the SoC maker (Freescale)?

Comment: ROM = Read Only Memory. Sometimes first-stage bootloader is stored on EEPROM, which gives you possibility to create your own custom first-stage bootloader.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Yes, factory first-stage bootloader comes from SoC manufacturer, of course.

Comment: depends on how wide and deep the watchdog timer reset goes, if it wipes out the whole chip then certainly you need to re-initialize the ddr controller (assuming that is on chip), but on the other end of the spectrum the wdt could just be a interrupt to the core (how is that useful? but I have seen it) which allows the software to choose assuming you actually recover from whatever you needed the wdt to save you from.

Comment: Resetting the DDR _controller_ is one thing; resetting the DDR _chip_ is another. There might be intermittent reboot problems if one is done and not the other (e.g. if unlucky enough to reset during a write burst). I wondered if that sort of problem is what prompted the OP's question...?

Answer (score -2):

note uboot, etc are not required they are GROSS overkill, they are operating systems in their own right.  to load and run linux you need memory up and running copy the kernel branch to it with some registers set to point at tables that you setup or copied from flash along with the kernel.

What you do on a cold reset or warm is up to you, same chip and board no reason necessarily why any two solutions have to do the exact same thing unless it is driven by hardware (if you do a wdt reset to start over and that reset wipes out the whole chip including the ddr controller).  You just have to put the system in the same state that linux expects.

Comment: U-Boot is not operating system, it just provides you a shell, that's all.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs have you actually examined uboot, it is a significantly large program with ip stacks, etc, it is in no way shape or form a simple baremetal bootloader.

Comment: That is absolutely true. But still, U-Boot is not an OS, it's just a bootloader on steroids. It's incredibly good for development, but of course absolute overkill and security flaw for release product. It was not me who -1'd you, by the way, I welcome all reasonable answers on this site.

Comment: I didnt look in detail but to facilitate those features it would be sane to have an os or rtos under it (uboot), like redboot which is similar and certainly does sit on an rtos in order to facilitate the same kinds of features.   Thats okay, there are a number of folks that dont really understand hardware or software, bootloaders, etc to understand what I am saying.  Dont ever look behind the curtain to actually understand things, just make assumptions...

Comment: to say it another way perhaps if you use u-boot, the ddr question has to do with how you design your u-boot port (and at times affected by the specific thing you are porting to), even if the warm reset doesnt reset the DDR controller, you may still choose to reset the ddr controller every time.  Or you add software to check and see if this was a warm reset or not if the controller, and other items are up, and choose to re-initialize them hot or not.  the question is very broad as every time it has been ported could have been a different solution (falling into one if a few major categories)

Comment: and we cant explain the reboot process in detail as it is soc/bootloader/implementation specific.

Comment: u-boot is just one of the popular bootloaders, not the only one, slowly being passed over.